# R: where to find the source code for all Rfast functions

Tags: r, rcpp

I have just found an incredibly useful package called Rfast which uses Rcpp to perform routine operations. So I would like to extend my thanks to them for their work, as well as to the creators of Rcpp of course.

Might be a stupid question but does anyone know where I can get the source code for the `Rfast` `rowOrder` function? Doesn't seem to be on their [github](https://github.com/RfastOfficial/Rfast/tree/master/src) although the code for another function like `Sort` is there.

---

EDIT: I would like to see the actual cpp code of the underlying function that performs the operations, which in the end is called `row_order_p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, it was in the col/row utilities at this address: https://github.com/RfastOfficial/Rfast/blob/2cc0ddcaa1f6a4844733871b259ce44b9e48d279/src/col_row_utilities_p.cpp

```
IntegerMatrix row_order_p(NumericMatrix x,const bool stable,const bool descending){
  const int ncl=x.ncol(),nrw=x.nrow();
  IntegerMatrix f(nrw,ncl);
  mat xx(x.begin(),nrw,ncl,false);
  imat ff(f.begin(),nrw,ncl,false);
  #ifdef _OPENMP
    #pragma omp parallel for
    #endif
    for(int i=0;i<nrw;++i){
      ff.row(i)=Order<irowvec,rowvec>(xx.row(i),stable,descending,1);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: I think Dirk answered the question you *asked* which is about the `rowOrder` function, vice the question you seem to have *meant* which is about the underlying code for `Rfast_row_order_p`.

Comment: I am curious although, what do you want it?

Comment: Hey Manos, reading your source code will hopefully allow me to increase my meagre c++ skills. Haven't done enough source code reading but this is definitely worth it. I was also searching for a fast `paste_by_row` function that would allow me to quickly paste all the columns of a dataframe by row, in order to generate unique row keys, but so far my efforts yield similar speed to what is available in `data.table`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I see it here: https://github.com/RfastOfficial/Rfast/search?q=rowOrder

Which then leads to https://github.com/RfastOfficial/Rfast/blob/343808948622137707563425a2f5624b58ec19f0/R/Order.R

Comment: Thanks Dirk, but I can't see the source of the function itself,  just that they are using `.Call(Rfast_row_order_p,x,stable,descending)`, do you think that there is a way to see the cpp code of what is called  by `.Call` such as with the other function I mentioned?

Comment: Found it - it is in the utilities.

Comment: Adapting Dirk's search: https://github.com/RfastOfficial/Rfast/search?q=Rfast_row_order_p